# Configuring different target URLs after login according to user roles (grails spring security) grails 2.3.3 spring-security-core:2.0-RC2

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am trying the common issue of configuring different URLs according to Roles using grails 2.3.3 and spring security spring-security-core:2.0-RC2.

I've found the following posts:
[first post](http://omarello.com/2011/09/grails-custom-target-urls-after-login/) and a 
modification in a second post http://desmontandojava.blogspot.com/2013/08/grails-tip-different-url-depending-on.html

but none of them work for my version, references didn't work for my version or packages are different now, they are all based on Burt Beckwith excellent presentation about hacking the spring security plugin,   but they seem to be outdated, has anyone tried this with a recent version of grails and spring-security-core spring-security-ui?

I also tried the simple version of simply asking in a controller for the role and redirecting but it didn't work either, it had an odd behavior.

Comment: It started working after I commented out this line in UrlMappings.groovy   // "/"(controller:"console", action:"myaction")

Comment: The only drawback is that when I logout there is no default page, but I know I can do this some other way, I'm going to read the posts that talk about redirecting after logout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Link worked for me:http://desmontandojava.blogspot.com/2013/08/grails-tip-different-url-depending-on.html

But only after I commented out this line in UrlMappings.groovy

// "/"(controller:"console", action:"myaction")

I was able to accomplish the task, however I had a problem, when logged out, the application was redirected to root and I did not have index.gsp so there was an error, then the only thing I did was add this property to Config.groovy.

grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.afterLogoutUrl='/login/auth'